# use variable outside of my function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use variable `current` outside of my function, I tried many logic's but i just got `undefined variable` in console. Is there something that i am missing or doing wrong?

```
var interval = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
  interval = setInterval(updateDiv, 1000);
});

function updateDiv() {
  var previous = "";
  var postIDAPI = "http://localhost/test/json.php?shortURL=1";
  $.getJSON(postIDAPI, function(json) {
    var current = json.postid;
    console.log('PostID : ', current);
    $("#address").html(current);
    if (previous !== current) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });
};
var postID = current;
//here i want to use variable current
```

Thanks, Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Don't define it in the function? But then you'll run into that whole "A" part of Ajax.

Comment: Why would you want this? Having a variable outside will clutter the global scope.

Comment: You could declare it globally outside the updateDiv() function, but bearing your ajax use why would you want to do that?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You want to use `current` before it could even have gotten a value. `var postID = current;` is executed before `updateDiv` was ever called. Also, `updateDiv` is potentially called multiple times which could assign different values to `current`.

Comment: actually i need that because i want to use that variable in another function.. i tried globally but it always returns undefined_variable

Comment: @RiskyJatt I think you need to take a step back and consider how asynchronous programming works. The only time that value is consistently valid is in the success callback itself.

Comment: *"i want to use that variable in another function"* How/when/where is that function executed?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to change the scope of `current`?

Comment: actually i am a noob, can someone here help me out with code? :(

Answer (score 4):

Declare current at a higher scope so that it is available there, and then reference it directly (without a `var` statement) in your inner function, like so:

```
var interval = null;
var current;
$(document).ready(function() {
    interval = setInterval(updateDiv, 1000);
});

function updateDiv() {
    var previous = "";
    var postIDAPI = "http://localhost/test/json.php?shortURL=1";
    $.getJSON(postIDAPI, function(json) {
        current = json.postid;
        console.log('PostID : ', current);
        $("#address").html(current);
        if (previous !== current) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });
}
var postID = current;
//here i want to use variable current
```

As commenter Dave Newton pointed out below, however, current will not actually be available at this point until the data is returned from your ajax call and your callback has executed-- as such, you may be better wrapping whatever additional functionality you need here in a `function` that's called at the end of your callback (if this is pertinent to your case).

Comment: This won't resolve the underlying issue of asynchronicity.

Comment: An excellent point-- my answer may as such prove to be insufficient-- I'll make a comment noting as such.

Comment: Also, since `updateDiv` will be called multiple times it's just illogical to access `current` once. It's almost paradoxical.

Comment: @FelixKling is this possible or not? if possible can you please provide some example with my code?

Comment: @RiskyJatt - I think FelixKling is stating not that it wouldn't _work_, per se, but that it's perhaps poorly thought out/designed (hopefully he or she doesn't mind my speculating as to their meaning).  However, without a clearer understanding of what it is you are trying to achieve, and why you are trying to achieve it in the way you are, it is hard to give you a better sense of whether or not it will work.  If you have some other code outside the block that variably runs that you want to have access to "current" then it should be fine.  If it needs to have access immediately, probably not...

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable outside `$(document).ready()`

```
var interval = null, current;

$(document).ready(function(){
    interval = setInterval(updateDiv,1000);
});

function updateDiv(){
    var previous = "";
    var postIDAPI = "http://localhost/test/json.php?shortURL=1";
    $.getJSON(postIDAPI, function (json) {
        current = json.postid;
        console.log('PostID : ', current);
        $("#address").html(current);
        if (previous !== current) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
   });
};
var postID = current;
```

Comment: This does not resolve the underlying issue of asynchronicity.

Comment: sorry but can you please explain ?

Comment: @mrid See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron?newsletter=1&nlcode=97716%7c4ba7